# JavaScript - Measure remote pages' load times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'd like to have a very simple page on my server, which uses JS to measure the time it takes to load the login web page on several remote URLs/servers. These servers are located around the world, and I'd like to measure the times in order to choose the fastest one for my location (i.e. the code will run client-side of course, on the user's browser).

**Example:**

server1.example.com: 200 ms

server2.example.com: 400 ms

server3.example.com: 2 ms

There's a lot of software that does this general idea (from simple pinging to wget, etc.), but I'm looking for JS code that I can use in a simple page which will try these requests and display the times.

The basic way I tried until now (simple Ajax requests using jQuery) doesn't work because of CORS errors. Any ideas for the simplest solution would be awesome.

Comment: You'll have to make the request from your backend instead.

Comment: @CertainPerformance but the whole idea is for the times to be relevant for the client-side location. I want to be able to let anyone with the link open the page and see their timings/latencies to the different servers.

Comment: I don't think it's possible from an ordinary web page, due to security. (if a site could do something like that, they could do some *really nasty things* using your credentials.) You'd need more privilege somehow, like with a userscript or browser extension

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks :) I thought it would be a problem. I'll try some other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load images without any restrictions, so take advantage of them:

```js
function ping(url) {
 var img = new Image(),
 start = Date.now();

 img.onload = function () {
  console.log(url, 'loaded in', Date.now() - start, 'ms');
 };

 img.src = url + '?' + Math.random();
 document.body.appendChild(img);
}

ping('https://facebook.com/favicon.ico');
ping('https://www.bing.com/favicon.ico');
ping('https://youtube.com/favicon.ico');
```

By the way, for accurate results, make sure the images are the same size.